# Drupal -- Node Reference, and Entity Reference are great -- I need "Menu Reference"

Tags: menu, drupal-7

Is there a Menu reference so I can attach menus to nodes, and render them on the page?

I'm looking for a solution which is equivalent to Node and/or Entity Reference modules.  Should I add that "Menu" is not a bundle in either?

Comment: Agreed - Don't down vote a question just because you don't understand it...

Comment: Since you've asked this on our [Drupal SE site](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13807/drupal--node-reference-and-entity-reference-are-great--i-need-menu-reference), I'm closing this out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such mechanism in Drupal - either core or contributed.

What you need to do to simulate this is:

1. Under "menu" - create as many menus as you need.
2. Under "Block" - you'll see that you have a block for each menu,
   place your menu block in the block position that you want it to appear.
3. Under each block's setting - tell the menu block on which pages you
       want it to appear.

It's a little tedious, but you have to understand that a CMS like Drupal is developed to satisfy the masses. It's generally considered poor design to do this because it makes navigation difficult for users. Having said that, you may have a perfectly valid reason for wanting to do that - but I wouldn't expect a module offering this functionality to popup anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Yes -- I'm familiar with the normal manual way, but as I read your approach I realized I could hack it by offering a select list of all menus as a custom field on the node edit screen.  Then, on node_load, I could grab that field, and load the associated menu into a block, which could get plunked on the page.  A bit less tedious.  Yes, the design I'm building calls for this sort of functionality.  Not my choice.  Thanks for being a sounding board.

Comment: Best answer -- see this page: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13807/node-reference-and-entity-reference-are-great-i-need-menu-reference